# pivot column into row titles in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe

```
division | category
  A      |    tools
  A      |    work
  B      |    tools
  B      |    books
```

both columns are factor variables.
how do I pivot the category columns so that I get:

```
division | tools | books | work
   A         1               1
   B         1       1
```

I tried using dplyr

```
wide <- df %>%
    spread(division, category)
```

but I still get the same number of rows it hasn't collapsed them down to open per division?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option would be to create another column of 1 with `transform`, and use that column as the `value.var` in `dcast`

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(transform(df, ind=1), division~category, value.var='ind')
```

Or as @MichaelChirico mentioned, we can specify `fun.aggregate` as `length`

```
dcast(df, division~category, length)
```

Or if we are using `dplyr/tidyr`, `mutate` the dataset to create the new column and then `spread` from 'long' to 'wide'. `spread` always needs the column that contains the value to put into the output `data.frame`. This was not present in the example of the OP, and adding it solves the issue.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   mutate(ind=1) %>% 
   spread(category,ind)
```

Comment: perhaps `dcast(setDT(df),division~category,fun.agg=length)` is the desired value? @akrun Depends if OP wants a count or simply an indicator

Comment: Nice! But could you explain why the code of the OP did not work. The main trick is in adding the `ind` column, but an explanation of the why would greatly increase the usefullness of this question.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra  Thanks, I was updating with some description.  Hope it is more clear.

Comment: I added some more detail, please reverse if you do not like it.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra  Thanks for adding the extra detail.  It helps.